# Reposting questions and answers from GitHub to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

There are many issues whose answers are on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub), but, due to a poor question-answer model, it's harder to find those answers, especially when a long conversation is going on, and the answer is somewhere within that conversation. Is it OK to re-post those issues with answers from GitHub to Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

GitHub Issues is just an issue tracker; it's not a Q&A platform and was never meant to be one.

If an issue is a bug report, it is not appropriate on Stack Overflow, since a bug report is not really a question. As mentioned, GitHub Issues is exactly the place to post bug reports anyway so they should stay there.

If an issue is "how do I solve this coding problem?", then it's no different from any other coding problem already on Stack Overflow. Provided the question is clear, reasonably scoped and includes the code necessary to reproduce the problem, etc, it should be fine.

If you copy an existing post from GitHub, the rules on attribution apply as usual. See [this help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) for help on referencing content written elsewhere.

Comment: *"GitHub Issues is just an issue tracker; it's not a Q&A platform"* - yet many projects do end up using GitHub issues for Q&A alongside issue reporting, either because it's less stressful to answer some idiot's question than to have to endure their whining about you closing it, or because the authors aren't particularly religious about information being in its proper place and can't resist an interesting puzzle once asked, or *as a deliberate choice*. New repos even come with a "question" label by default, so such usage hardly seems to be against GitHub's intent.