# Can't there be a direct lift of the ban or the option to specifically answer only questions tagged for the library he is a committer for?

Tags: feature-request, answers, post-ban

Recently I created the tag [pf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pf4j) for the Plugin Framework for Java for [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53280499/why-is-the-result-of-pluginmanager-getextensions-empty).

[The committer of the framework](https://github.com/pf4j/pf4j/commits?author=decebals) would like to answer my question.

However, [his Stack Overflow account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1607495/decebal) seems to be in a ban status. He sent me the following screenshot:

[image: Ban notice]

Now I have been looking around in the help center and I am a bit confused.

It seems to answer he first has to post a decent question again. But it seems he'll only get an opportunity to do so every 6 months.

Now I'd actively like to get an answer from him. Why should he have to post a question first?

**Feature Request:**

**Can't there be a direct lift of the ban or the option to specifically answer only questions tagged for the library he is a committer for?**

Comment: Clearly he is going to have to provide support a different way.  Nothing that can't be done at github.com, click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/pf4j/pf4j/issues).  Do consider editing the tag wiki to point out that this is the best way to get help.

Comment: The question is not so much about support any more. I was able to create a workaround for the issue myself. I think the Q&A format of stackoverflow is much more useable to discuss the topic. On the other hand this is another Meta discussion: how should github issues and stackoverflow questions be handled in respect to each other. More often than not i link such items together having a link from stackoverflow to github and vice versa. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287021/1497139

Comment: _"Discussing a topic"_ is rarely a good use of our Q&A format.

Comment: If that user wants to be able to answer questions again, they could *participate and contribute to the site*.

Comment: The fact that this user got answer banned is because his answers aren't deemed of high quality to the site. What's the benefit in unblocking him just to get more low quality answers?

Comment: The ban is many years old and has blocked the user from participating at all. He did not understand the procedure how to get the ban lifted. I do personally understand part of the procedure but see no benefit in keeping somebody out of the community for so many years. I personally find the stackoverflow rules much too harsh compared what you see in law. In europe the standard limitation is around 3 years since a few years.

Comment: That may be, but that's a completely different issue and a completely different FR, if you want to post it (I haven't done the research and I do not know if something like that has been asked in the past).

Comment: I'm going to guess that he's got a ton of answers that were actually him trying to get information out of the question asker. They all got downvoted and deleted and now he's banned. The only solution is for him to flag one of his posts (or your post), select "other" and ask for links to his deleted answers. He then has to edit them into acceptable answers and request they be undeleted.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this - i would have not known what to do from what I have read in the FAQ. I have now offered the user to do a remote session together with him in the hope that my experience might help him avoiding common mistakes for the first new steps. By the way - is he also banned from meta?

Comment: No, they are not banned from meta. Question bans in main do not imply a ban in meta. Unless they are suspended, which doesn't look like, they can ask in meta to their heart's content.

Comment: *It seems to **answer** he first has to post a decent **question** again.* They're not question banned though, right?

Comment: If he has been banned for "long", he has a chance every 6 months to post an answer. So if he was still banned when he was trying to answer you.... that means he posted another answer < 6 months ago

Comment: Deleted answers, score <= 0: ([1](//stackoverflow.com/a/13157766) [2](//stackoverflow.com/a/13157628) [3](//stackoverflow.com/a/12860203) [4](//stackoverflow.com/a/12814854) [5](//stackoverflow.com/a/12010125)), none of which seem recent.

Comment: I can not follow the links in Samuel Liews comment. This seems to be part of the issue - how to lift the ban if helping in analyzing is made difficult by non visible stuff.

Comment: @WolfgangFahl The links are meant so the incumbent user can  edit their posts. Users like us under 10k reputation can't see deleted posts, but the owner of those posts can use these links to get to their deleted posts and hopefully edit them into shape, to undelete them afterwards.

Answer (score 24):

Disregarding the added complexity something like this would entail, it simply boils down to this:

**The fact that someone maintains a specific product or library does not mean that they know how (or are willing) to follow Stack Overflow rules.**

In this specific case, since they are already answer-banned, it would seem they **didn't** follow the rules in the past. If they want to recover from this ban, I think is best that they follow [the usual procedure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

#### Nay, from me.