# Suggesting that users can get help on other websites

Tags: discussion

Sometimes on Stack Overflow people ask questions that can't easily be answered within this format and they get ignored or downvoted, etc.

In situations like this is it acceptable to suggest to the user that they can get help on Codementor or would I get told off for doing this? Full disclosure, I am a mentor on Codementor, which is a service where users pay to get help.

Comment: I would suggest if you are recommending an alternative website, you note your affiliation, if any. Otherwise it could (would) be seen as spam.

Comment: And only do so in comments, not as an answer.

Comment: I often recommend trying other sites. In your case it's easy as you have one in mind. Refrain from telling the asker to go elsewhere without suggesting a site that you feel comfortable recommending because if the asker googles something up odds are uncomfortably high that they'll wind up on a site that makes them a WORSE programmer.

Comment: As long as you focus on why *the question* doesn't go well in the Q/A model and that *the question* might go well on a forum/chat/mentor/tutor site, then you should be okay. The user is welcome to try another question later that does fit the Q/A model. A link to the help center can help for background on what is different on a Q/A site. And if you redirect to something you're affiliated with, do disclose that upfront.

Comment: What about chat? E.g. seeing your tags, there’s a [JavaScript room](//chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) and a [Python room](//chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python).

Comment: I wouldn't specifically name a single site though, in essence the target audience should use "the web" and there are a whole host of sites available where the question might land. Leave the choice up to them. Besides, you don't want to become "that person on Stack Overflow" in the eyes of Codementor.

Comment: Leave the choice of site up to the asker you're assuming the asker has sufficient ability to recognize bad code and practice and won't just pick and learn from whatever they find. Typically someone asking a question that requires more of a tutoring/mentoring approach won't be able to recognize they've landed on a site run by or filled with folks who are no better, or even worse, programmers than they are.

Comment: [Codementor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codementor) - *"... an online platform providing instant one-on-one help for software developers by utilizing screen sharing, video and text chat, in order to replicate for users the experience of having a mentor for code reviewing, debugging, and online programming. ... marketplace platform ... with rates set by the mentor themselves"*. I think the percentage of Stack Overflow users interested in this would be very low.

Comment: I think you should disclose your economic interest in your question here.

Comment: It is a judgment call. If a question can't be answered on SO, it was off-topic to begin with. When there are questions, such as those specific to a Linux distribution, etc.. I don't have any problem referring them to, e.g. the Arch-general mailing list or elsewhere where they can get help with their question (generally in the comment closing the question)

Comment: *within this format and they get ignored or downvoted* => It would be helpful if you post format or reference questions, that are not answered, ignored, or downvoted. did you ask *user* for reference questions or have you ever reviewed those questions in SO?

Comment: Why not just vote to close the question using the **Other** option: _"I’m voting to close this question because...."_? I suspect most here wouldn't be opposed to close voting a question in that manner if (say) it was asked in Spanish. Why shouldn't a question _"that can't easily be answered within this format"_ be treated in the same way? Of course you could still leave a comment with your recommendations along with your close vote.

Answer (score 5):

Focusing specifically within the realm of Stack Overflow / programming, then users are *recommended* to follow all steps on [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

If their question falls far outside of any reasonable attempt to solve the problem themselves (a homework dump, shows no research, etc), or posts a big code block without reducing the question to an MCVE, then downvote; vote to close as too broad, needs debugging details, etc. and move on.

If they are asking about other things, then vote to close as belonging to another site. You can comment to say this, but not necessary, IMO. Development often has overlapping questions that, when specific, are more suited for the other Stack Exchange sites.

- software or non-programming - [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour)
- Networking - [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour)
- [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)
- [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)

> Is it acceptable to suggest [off-site resource]

In my opinion, no.

Their question may be for them, but the answer should be for anyone that searches for the same problem.

If you happen to get them into a [Codementor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codementor) (or similar site) session, at least post the answer back to the main question, but if you do this often enough, it is acting as a form of affiliate marketing and your account may get flagged as spam.

Comment: "Their question may be for them, but the answer should be for anyone that searches for the same problem. If ..., at least post the answer back" - wait, isn't this about questions that are off topic (and thus should be deleted and not answered)?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if the questions should instead be bug reports/feature requests in an external bug tracker.

If you are a maintainer/contributor of a package and the user asks a question that turns out to be due to a bug (which is still a [valid question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287021/6646912)), I believe it is acceptable to ask the OP to fill in the bug report on GitHub/another website or to contribute to an existing discussion.

It is crucial that this is allowed as it allows open-source maintainers to get a repository-specific issue template filled in, and allows to discuss the remediation strategy with the affected users directly, which may be out of scope, or result in a prolonged discussion on SO. The alternative of having this discussion in the comments on SO would be detrimental to the repository maintainability (no trace of the discussion/question or comments can be deleted, outside of maintainers control).

It is a good practice to come back once the issue is resolved and post an answer explaining the details (to which version users should upgrade and how, describe any workarounds for an older version, etc). An [earlier answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398253/6646912) even recommends posting an answer with a link to a relevant issue not distinguishing if it was resolved or not, but I usually just post it as a comment until the issue is resolved at our end.

Comment: And that would definitely be a valid edge case.

Answer (score 3):

I personally feel that if a question is so "unanswerable" utilizing the SO interface, it's because the question was poorly formed to begin with. And in that case, no, I don't think recommending someone to Codementor or anywhere else is a good idea.

Why? Because rather than correcting the user and directing them toward a more thorough review and understanding of what the problem actually is, you're basically offering a kind of crutch and saying "good luck to ya."

It also serves as a catalyst (by way of encouragement) to the ever growing number of low-quality questions being posted on SO.

If you can't ask a question in a way it can be answered here, then the asker hasn't spent much time trying to understand the problem to begin with. Should you try to profit off that shortcoming with your Codementor account? I guess it's not technically unethical... Some people like being spoon-fed. But I think it's a poor habit to nurture here at SO.

My experience has been that SO has a very high quality and experienced group of individuals who are looking at the question. If you can't get someone here to give you a meaningful answer, then my statements above are the reason. I struggle to even think of edge cases... Maybe someone can present one I'm not thinking of, so as to clarify where this *might* be appropriate.

Comment: "*the asker hasn't spent much time trying to understand the problem*" - or they just don't know how to do that, which is what mentoring could help with. Learning to write good questions is a skill on its own, and it's taught elsewhere. "*Some people like being spoon-fed. But I think it's a poor habit to nurture here at SO.*" - why do you think it would nurture this habit if we close their question here at SO? I think that leaving them a comment where else to go is just helpful if they are new to the ecosystem.

Comment: While many users asking off topic questions just need to do some more research, it is quite dismissive to assume that *all* of them are just lazy, rather than there being plenty who simply haven't learnt how to do said research yet (and it would be even more dismissive to say teaching them that is "spoonfeeding"). I see a whole lot of questions where the asker needs mentorship rather than a direct answer, because the latter (which is what SO focuses on) will only solve their immediate problem without giving them the tools to solve similar problems.

Comment: If you think a mentor spoonfeeds you, then... you haven't had any good mentors. A good mentor teaches you how to solve your problems yourself.

Comment: Here at SO, there are guidelines which govern the acceptability of a question. And for good reason. If a user cannot (or simply isn't yet qualified in their journey as a developer to)  adhere to the standards,  we shouldn't encourage low quality posts by giving referrals. With all the recent lamentations about question quality, I figured this would be a given. For this reason, I do feel  it's a bad idea to foster the notion of redirecting users elsewhere. This came out matter-of-factly; this is only my opinion and I totally respect where you guys are coming from.

Comment: @silencedogood "Go and ask someone else" is not exactly the most welcoming response that would encourage them to ask similar questions in future (because they'd know to ask those elsewhere; but, if phrased politely, they may be more likely to come back if they have an appropriate question). We currently have an epidemic of people thinking they can get an answer to pretty much anything programming-related here (and they often can). Rather than trying to stomp out people's naturally tendency to help others, it would probably be easier to get them to tell people where and how to can get an answer

Comment: If we start having (or want to avoid) an epidemic of people using SO as a "tell me where this belongs or how to get an answer to this" service (which I honestly don't think would be a huge concern, but anyway), then we can potentially just point people to a Meta post or some offsite resource, that covers some of the basics about which programming questions belong where, instead of actually giving them specific advice in the question (meaning they only ever get pointed to one place, therefore there is basically no reason to ask a question they know is off topic).

Answer (score 2):

I quite often see questions that just misunderstand what Stack Overflow is all about. I am as firm as just about anybody that people should read carefully what is and what is not on offer, but we all know that often they don't.

My direct experience is almost entirely with users of statistical software. Many of their questions would look lazy, lousy, or both to very many programmers. However, they are often naively hoping that SO may be a place to help with coding, usually when their problem is that they have no code or are working with other people's code and want to go beyond it.

I see no contradiction between firmly down-voting, voting to close, and explaining why such posters are not meeting the expectations of SO -- and also giving positive advice about where the OP might be better served, chiefly dedicated forums where there is much more tolerance, even an expectation that clueless beginners need to start somewhere.

Other answers I've read seem to lack any inclination to show any help at all. The refrain is "Such questions should not be asked, so the OP should just be told to go away." That is right, but nothing rules out adding a gentler message "Sorry, but we don't sell that here, yet X may be a better bet for you".

Although aimed at the OP, such advice should be helpful to others in a similar situation -- while a thread remains visible (and ideally that wouldn't be long).

I have no experience with Codementor and offer no comments on it. The OP's question starts with "help on other websites" and ends by focusing on Codementor.

Comment: Codementor is not a volunteer site. It is a paid service (there is *almost* literally a monetary exchange for every second of every interaction).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks for information. FWIW, my comments are entirely about suggesting  sites loosely comparable with SE where any advice or help is entirely free.

Answer (score -5):

No, for the simple fact that I can't say with absolute *certainty* that you are willing to accept our refuse.

Comment: @NotThatGuy:  We turn down a broad variety of questions because we're not a help desk.  I don't want to dump the questions that we didn't want to answer onto some other website because they *think* they could handle it.  I especially wouldn't want to just based on a single representative of that site, as well.

Comment: Oh, "you" is "that site", not "OP".

Comment: What does this have to do with the question at hand?

Comment: @qwr: It directly addresses it. "Can I recommend that someone ask their question elsewhere because it's off topic on Stack Overflow" presumes that, to begin with, the target location even *wants* the question, putting aside for now the quality of the question...